# Limit axis range on pdp plot from gbm package at R

Tags: r, gbm

I am trying to limit the x-axis of a partial dependency plot (so that the interesting region effectively gets enlarged). I have tried using the xlim option but it didn't work.

I have created a quick example to replicate the problem:

```
library(gbm)

xdata <- iris

# reformulate problem as binary classification
xdata$Species <- as.character(xdata$Species)
change.classes <- function(prev) {
  if (prev == 'setosa') {
    return(1)
  }
  else return(0)
}
ydata <- as.integer(sapply(xdata$Species, change.classes))
xdata$Species <- NULL

# train gbm model
set.seed(250)
fit <- gbm(ydata ~ ., data = xdata,
           distribution = 'bernoulli',
           n.trees = 100,
           interaction.depth = 3,
           n.minobsinnode = 10,
           shrinkage = 0.03,
           bag.fraction = 0.5,
           train.fraction = 1.0)

# plot partial dependency plot
plot.gbm(fit, i.var = "Petal.Length", n.trees = 95, xlim = c(2,3))
```

As you can see the following image [image] the x - axis ranges from 1 to 7 covering all the values of the dataset despite me having set xlim.

How can I make xlim to work properly (and limit the graph to the range between 2 and 3)? Alternatively is there any other way to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure why the `xlim` argument is ignored here, as it works as expected with the example in the `gbm` help. In any case, you can use the `return.grid` argument to `plot.gbm` to get the x and y values used for the plot and then create your own plot. For example:

```
fit.dat = plot(fit, i.var="Petal.Length", n.trees=95, return.grid=TRUE)

plot(fit.dat$Petal.Length, fit.dat$y, type="l", xlim=c(2,3))
```

Comment: Cool, thanks. Maybe xlim not working is a bug? Not sure how to check that and/or where to go to submit it.

Comment: You could go to the [`gbm` package development page on Github](https://github.com/harrysouthworth/gbm/issues) and submit this as a potential bug in the `issues` tab.

Comment: I looked at the gbm repository and they have a [pull request](https://github.com/gbm-developers/gbm/pull/119) that fixes this but it hasn't made it into a release yet.

Answer (score 1):

You can also try the `pdp` package; this package is aimed at constructing PDPs for various types of fitted models in R. Note however, that this package is more general and does not exploit the same computational shortcuts that GBM does.

```
# Development version works with gbm models
devtools::install_github("bgreenwell/pdp")

# Load the pdp package
library(pdp)

# Use plotPartial to change x-axis limits
fit %>%
  partial(pred.var = "Petal.Length", grid.resolution = 100, n.trees = 95) %>% 
  plotPartial(xlim = c(2, 3))
```

Even better, create your own grid of predictor values:

```
xgrid <- data.frame(Petal.Length = seq(from = 2, to = 3, length = 100))

partial(fit, pred.var = "Petal.Length", pred.grid = xgrid, 
        plot = TRUE, n.trees = 95)
```